# Advanced Powershell Error Handling for Microsoft Modules (eg Lync)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a fairly complex script that includes Lync functionality.  For this I import the PSSession.

When one of these commands errors, my error handling returns the line and command within the Lync module it fails on (eg line 2055 $steppablePipeline.End() ) instead of the line and command in my code (eg line 18 Enable-CSUser)

Is there some way to capture my calling command and line?

The following is a simplified example of the script

```
Function Main 
{
    Try 
    {
        LyncTest
        MailboxTest
    }
    Catch {$rtn = ReturnErrorCatch $_ ; Return $rtn}                            #Return Failure
}
Function MailboxTest
{
    $script:callline = (Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptLineNumber
    Get-Mailbox "kfsjlxghkjsdh" -ErrorAction:Stop
}
Function LyncTest
{
    $script:callline = (Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptLineNumber
    Enable-CSUser "kfsjlxghkjsdh" -ErrorAction:Stop
}
Function ReturnErrorCatch ($catch)
{
    If ($catch.InvocationInfo.InvocationName -eq "throw"){$errorreturn = $catch.Exception.Message.ToString()}
    Else
    {
        $line = "Line: " + $catch.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber.ToString()
        $exception = $catch.Exception.Message.ToString() -replace "`n"," "
        $command = "Command: " + ($catch.InvocationInfo.Line.ToString() -replace "`t","").Trim()
        $activity = " (Activity: " + $catch.CategoryInfo.Activity +")"
        $line = $line + "(" + $callline.ToString() + ")"
        $errorreturn = $line + " " + $exception + "`r`n" + $command + $activity
    }
    $Output = New-Object PSObject -Property @{Result=1;ResultReason=$errorreturn}
    Return $Output
}
$result = Main
$result | fl
```

This returns:

```
Result       : 1
ResultReason : Line: 2055(5) If SIP address type (SipAddressType) is set to None or is not set, you must specify the SIP address (SipAddress).
           Command: $steppablePipeline.End() (Activity: Enable-CsUser)
```

Within my script, I am able to get the calling line by putting the $script:callline line within every subfunction (better ways to do this?), so if I comment out the LyncTest, and run the mailboxtest, I get the expected error return with erroring command, the line it failed on, and the line the function was called from.

As this is for Exchange 2010, I cannot use any Powershell V3 functionality, it must be V2.